# How accurately can the distance of a star be measured?

Tags: astronomy, stars, error-analysis, distance, parallax

With the launch of the GAIA mission some years ago, a new precedent was set in mankind's ability to map our universe. However, how accurate are the distances created by this? From [ESA's website](https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Gaia/Frequently_Asked_Questions_about_Gaia), I found:

> In the final Gaia catalogue, expected in the early 2020s, brighter objects (3-13 magnitude) will have positions measured to a precision of 5 microarcseconds, parallaxes to 6.7 microarcseconds, and proper motions to 3.5 microarcseconds per year

If we take the value 6.7, and put that into the equation: d=1/p, we get d=1/0.0000067=150,000 parsecs. This is immensely accurate given that most sources tell me that the most accurate is around 1000 parsecs (accurate to 0.001 arcseconds).
Are my calculations correct, or did I use a wrong value somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking if ESA made a mistake?

Comment: I'm asking if I'm calculating it correctly

Comment: O, I see. I will change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is the accuracy. So for a star at 15.000 parsec that is a parallax of 67 micro arcsec this would mean a 10% accuracy of that distance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't understand where 10% accuracy comes from? Would a star at 1,500 parsecs have 1% accuracy then?

Comment: Correct. 1500 parsec corresponds to 670 micro arcsec and the precision of 6.7 micro arcsec gives 1 % precision of the distance, so $\pm$ 15 parsec.